# Select Jamroot file for bjam

Tags: makefile, bjam

Is is possible to invoke bjam with Jamroot.jam file in a different directory than current working directory, just like it is possible to select Makefile from make command line interface:

```
make -f ../../MyMakefile MyTargetName

bjam ../../MyBjamFile.jam MyTargetName
```

??

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to use a different Jamfile/Jamroot.  But you can refer to projects in other directories.

```
bjam ../..//MyTargetName
```

That will create the target named `MyTargetName` defined in ../../Jamfile (or ../../Jamroot).  The following might work, but I'm not sure:

```
bjam ../../MyBjamFile.jam//MyTargetName
```

That should find the correct target, but will probably still traverse the parent directories looking for a Jamroot file, which may or may not exist.